# DVD-RW: can read in all computers but one

Tags: dvd

I burned an ISO image of a Linux distribution in a DVD-RW disc that I had. The disc is quite old (it only supports up to 2x burning speed), but after burning it, the resulting disc was recognized in both of my computers, a PC and a Macbook Pro. However, when I took it to a HP G62 laptop, it didn't recognize the disc at all; instead, it shows up in the DVD drive as an empty disc ("4.3 Gb. free space"). The laptop's DVD drive, as far as I could find out, supports both +RW and -RW.

Why causes this? I thought that perhaps the disc is too old, but as I mentioned, both of my computers can read it perfectly.

Comment: Did you "close" the disc when you burned it? If not, try closing it. Also make sure the HP can read other discs.

Comment: Try burning the image using the HP, and do the reverse. It could just be a glitch with the DVD drive.

Comment: HP drive busted or not compatible?

Comment: It was an ISO image, so there shouldn't be any need for "closing", right? As long as you pick the option of burning as an image, the software should close the disc automatically. As for the rest of the suggestions, I'll test them as soon as I have access to the HP laptop again.

Comment: This can happen if the burning laser is weak, or clouded from airborn contaminates not making a strong burn. It can also happen just from minor inconsistancies between drive units, just being pickey , some will be pickey on thier ability to read one type or brand or another.  There is pages and pages about this at the cd-dvd sites about what is "most compatable" in both media and the burners making it.  The solution is try other media, when that doesnt work try other burner.  You already covered the drives ability to recognise various formats of drives.  try a -R without the W

Comment: I think pre-SP2 Windows XP has trouble recognising many DVD-R(W) formats. What OS and buring software package did you use?

Comment: Oh, I don't think that's the problem. The HP laptop is using Windows 7. I burned the image with ImgBurn, also under Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Some brands of disks just don't work on some computers... if you have another of the same disks I would burn it again just like you did the first one to test this theory.

My boyfriend was burning disks for a guy and he thought they weren't burning because after he burned one he looked at it and the computer showed it as blank... luckily for him I stuck it in the dvd player and it worked just fine... the computer could burn it but not read it, which was very odd.